# Does the C++ 11 standard guarantees that std::atomic<> is implemented as a lock-free operation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'm at a junction, I'm trying to pick one between mutex-lock-based data structure and lock-free ( and possibly wait-free ) data structure.

While digging a little deeper I found no word about whether the C++11 standard supports lock-free operations for atomic types, not even for width-based integrals like `atomic_uint32_t` . In other words it's not just the `std::atomic<>` interface that is **not** granted to be lock-free; the only thing that looks like it's granted to be lock-free in the whole standard library is `std::atomic_flag` .

Is this true or I'm missing something ? What is the reason for that ? I mean the standard calls "atomic" something that is clearly not lock-free at all and it's something that is even allowed to use mutexes or blocking calls under the hood.

Comment: You are confusing the terms "atomic" and "lock-free". Obviously the atomic operations are guaranteed to be atomic, otherwise they would have a different name. You are correct that only `atomic_flag` is guaranteed to be lock-free.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ standard makes no guarantee that `std::atomic<T>` operations are lock-free. However, you can use `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()` to find out if the operation of `std::atomic<T>` is lock free 29.6.5 [atomics.types.operations.req] paragraph 7:

> Returns: True if the object’s operations are lock-free, false otherwise.

If it is not lock-free it will still do the required synchronization but it uses some lock to do so.

Comment: So am I right in inferring from your answer that "atomic" means "noninterruptible at cpu level"? Why was the name "atomic" chosen if it won't implement the meaning of its name, if so?

Comment: not really a big fan of this approach but at least I got a confirmation about what I was asking ...

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, the name "atomic" was likely chosen since the primary use of `std::atomic<T>` will be actual atomic operations on platforms that support them. The whole non-atomic aspect just seems to try to keep the standard platform agnostic.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub: The semantics of the atomic types is that the changes are made in an atomic and suitably thread-safe way. An implementation using licks does so. Another aspect of this approach is that different hardware supports different hardware-level atomic support and the chosen approach allows to implement the best approach possible for a given type.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - "atomic" in the C++ standard has three requirements: no data races, cache coherence, and no code movement across atomic operations. Other contexts may well use a different definition of "atomic", but any such other definitions are not applicable to C++ atomics.

Comment: I am confusing. I though using lock is just one way to implement atomic operation (compare to use atomic CAS) . Even lock is used, it is still atomic? So the standard make no guarantee that `std::atomic` provide lock-free implementation but it guarantee to provide atomic operation?

Comment: Downvoted. "Atomic" doesn't mean lock-free.

These operations are atomic, whether they use locks, or atomic CPU instructions. (In the former case, they are building atomicity as an abstraction, but they're still atomic)

Answer (score 10):

If by atomic you mean, using hardware support without locks, then yes, the standard doesn't give you a guarantee for that. Why? Well, because different architectures support different kind of hardware atomicity. `std::atomic<>` has the handy `is_lock_free()` method which can be used to check wether the given object is actually lock free, or uses a lock internally to guarantee atomic operations. You can use that and check on your target hardware wether it would be lock free or not, and then decide what data structure to go for.

However, that being said, if the target architecture has hardware support for atomic operations for the fixed width integrals you are interested in, and you didn't obtain your copy of the standard library from the the shady software shop in the ghetto, it's probably going to use the hardware instead of a full blown lock.

Comment: I don't get the meaning of this approach, the fact that there is a method named `is_lock_free()` doesn't solve any problem, locking and lock-free algorithms and data structures are 2 totally different worlds, with 2 totally different checks and balances. I can't imagine a C++ expert saying "Ok we describe std::atomic<> as "maybe it's atomic" but we also offer a method to check if it's lock free or not", just doesn't make sense in a business prospective, not even the naming makes much sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense once you realize that you have to support platforms that may have very different architectures.

Comment: @MarkusKoivisto: That's no argument for naming the two types both `std::atomic<T>`. Since you have to implement the algorithm twice anyway, you could use `atomic<T>` in the lock-free branch and plain `T` in the branch where you do the locking. The real problem is that with the current interface, you have to decide _at run time_  which algorithm to choose. It's not `constexpr`. Worse, you have to check it for every object since it's not even `static`. Every temporary has to be checked, too.

Comment: @MSalters: FWIW, C++17 added a `static constexpr bool` variable to `atomic<T>` called `is_always_lock_free`, so you can just `static_assert` if it isn't.