# Single bit manipulations with guaranteed atomicity

Tags: c++, multithreading, bit-manipulation, atomic

Is there a way to set, clear, test and flip a single bit as an atomic operation in c++? For example bitwise variants to "compare_and_swap".

Comment: `std::atomic_bool`?

Comment: There is no "C/C++". Pick *one*.

Comment: What architecture are you working with? If a given architecture has no support for bit level atomic operations then the language/compiler will not magically make it possible.

Comment: @Tony K the architecture is x86-64

Comment: check out std::bitset when using c++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Manipulating bits atomically requires a `compare_exchange` RMW to avoid touching other bits in the `atomic` variable.
Testing a bit is not a modifying operation, therefore a `load()` suffices.

You will have to add range error checking

```
template<typename T, typename OP>
T manipulate_bit(std::atomic<T> &a, unsigned n, OP bit_op)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "atomic type not integral");

    T val = a.load();
    while (!a.compare_exchange_weak(val, bit_op(val, n)));

    return val;
}

auto set_bit = [](auto val, unsigned n) { return val | (1 << n); };
auto clr_bit = [](auto val, unsigned n) { return val & ~(1 << n); };
auto tgl_bit = [](auto val, unsigned n) { return val ^ (1 << n); };


int main()
{
    std::atomic<int> a{0x2216};

    manipulate_bit(a, 3, set_bit);  // set bit 3

    manipulate_bit(a, 7, tgl_bit);  // toggle bit 7

    manipulate_bit(a, 13, clr_bit);  // clear bit 13

    bool isset = (a.load() >> 5) & 1;  // testing bit 5
}
```

Comment: Good; I would `return val;`, as knowing what you transitioned from is often useful.

Comment: Agree; it's actually closer to the design conventions that atomic operations follow

Comment: Am I missing something or shouldn't you update val within the loop? Otherwise you have a deadlock until a has its old value.

Comment: @morty If `compare_exchange_weak` returns false, it updates its first argument with the current value.  For that reason, the first argument (`val`), has to be an lvalue reference.

Comment: @LWimsey: Ah yes. Thanks. I really whish C++ would require a keyword to highlight that it's a lvalue reference and that it might be modified.

Comment: why not use fetch_or, fetch_and or fetch_xor ?

Comment: @deltanine: you're correct, the `1ULL<<n` or `T(1)<<n` part isn't part of the atomic operation, so `fetch_and/or/xor` are better ways to implement this.  Hopefully a compiler for x86 would turn `a.fetch_or(1<<n)` into `lock bts`, if the return value is only tested at bit-position `n`.  Or into `bts reg, reg` / `lock or` if the return value is unused.  Otherwise the compiler will use a `lock cmpxchg` retry loop for you, but it's still better to use a single `fetch_op` in the source since it can compile efficiently for other ISAs, especially ARMv8.1

Comment: [I made a terrible idea based on this](https://ideone.com/ZDMuTp)

Comment: [I made a much better idea based on this](https://ideone.com/QK6NSG) It now supports modifying multiple members of a bitfield, each of which can be multiple bits themselves, with conditional expressions. Very handy!

Answer (score 5):

To set a bit atomically in a `std::atomic<int> a` or `std::atomic<unsigned int> a`,
use `a.fetch_or(bit)` (also `|=` is overloaded, but that won't let you use an order weaker than seq_cst)

To atomically clear a bit in an atomic integer, you can use `a.fetch_and(~bit)` (also `&=`)

To atomically flip a bit in an atomic integer, you can use `a.fetch_xor(bit)` (also `^=`)

There are also non-member-function versions of these, like `std::atomic_fetch_or(&a, bit)`, but in ISO C++ it's not safe to point a `std::atomic_int*` at an `int` object.

---

To do atomic operations on a plain `int` variable, use [C++20 std::atomic_ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref/atomic_ref) `auto foo_atomic = std::atomic_ref<int>( foo )` and do `foo_atomic.fetch_or(bit)`.  This is only safe if no other threads are reading or writing the underlying object, only via their own `atomic_ref` objects.  Also, be sure to declare the underlying `int` with `alignas(std::atomic_ref<int>::required_alignment)`, especially for integer types wider than `int`.

Comment: These are not atomic operations when discussing multithreading

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: When you perform these sort of operations in one CPU, the C++ language offers no guarantee that the other CPUs will see the modified value.

Comment: Only bitwise atomic operations? What about the other std::atomic operations?

Comment: No operation is atomic on basic `int` and `bool`s, even bitwise operations.  `std::atomic<int>` and `std::atomic<bool>` are atomic, but the question and answer don't directly mention those.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The question doesn't say they need to do this on a plain `int`.  If they do, that's what C++20 std::atomic_ref is for (as long as no other threads can be accessing the plain int while you do this.)  Updated this answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Flipping a bit in an integer is just a compare and exchange operation. That you're using it to test and flip a single bit doesn't change anything. So a simple `compare_exchange_weak` loop will do this.

Comment: in compare_exchange_weak it is assumed that you know  the expected result. This is not the case in bit manipulations.

Comment: Note that C/C++ "atomics" is not the same as atomic operation in the sense of being uninterruptible, it simply guarantees a certain level of thread safety. For example stdatomic.h would not be suitable in kernel code interruptible by ISRs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900524/does-the-c-11-standard-guarantees-that-stdatomic-is-implemented-as-an-atom

Comment: @chook can't you do a read first to determine the expected result?

Comment: @chook If you know what the operation is, you can determine the expected result for any operation, bit operation or otherwise. You can use `compare_exchange_weak` to turn any non-atomic transformation of a value to an atomic one.