# std::atomic on struct bit-fields

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, atomic, bit-fields

I'm modifying some existing open source library and there is a struct (say named as Node) containing bit-fields, e.g.

```
struct Node {
    std::atomic<uint32_t> size:30;
    std::atomic<uint32_t> isnull:1;
};
```

To fit my needs, these fields need to be atomic so I was expecting to use std::atomic for this and faced compile time error:

```
bit-field 'size' has non-integral type 'std::atomic<uint32_t>'
```

According to documentation, there is a restricted set of types which can be used for std::atomic

Can anyone advise/have idea on how to get functionality of atomic fields with the minimum impact to the existing source code?

Comment: There ain't no such thing as an atomic bit field. A typical CPU simply doesn't provide machine instructions to manipulate a bit field atomically; and so the C++ language doesn't allow such a construct, as it would be unimplementable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik On which real world CPU would that be unimplementable?

Comment: @curiousguy On an x86, far as I can tell. At least, not without locks or a spin loop.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: A CAS retry-loop is lock-free, but yeah, I wouldn't expect a compiler to invent that for me!  If you want it, it would be much more efficient to write your own functions that e.g. can assume `fetch_add` doesn't overflow from `size` into `isnull`, or at least make you aware of the CAS retry loops necessary so you can do more stuff with a temporary and only try to CAS in the final result at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't atomically change bitfields, you either turn your bitfield into small functions (potentially fastest solution), or insert atomic locks and let the compiler handle the bitfield for tasks that will take longer;

(1) You can use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752087/13797696) to manipulate the bits of atomic integral numbers by defining manipulator functions and perhaps the bits manually. An example where `size` bitfield is defined most of the time;

```
# define NULLBIT 1 // chosen the lower bit to avoid overflow

std::atomic<uint32_t> Node;

auto add_ifdef = [](uint32_t val, int32_t a)
{
    return (val & NULLBIT) ? NULLBIT : (((val >> NULLBIT) + a) << NULLBIT);
};

auto v = Node.load();
while(Node.compare_exchange_weak(v, add_ifdef(v, -5)) {}
```

(2) Using a bitfield that needs atomicity is less ideal programmatically. Depending on the complexity of the task, you can sacrifice 8 bits and insert a `std::atomic_flag` (lock) in the bitfield with a union and spin lock it. It should perform better than creating, locking, unlocking with a `std::mutex` and `std::unique_lock`, to enable low cost multi-threading.

The reserved 8 bits are for the endian structure. You may have to define the lock at the end for big-endian processors. I only tested this code on an Intel CPU (always little-endian).

```
// Use when the operation is quick to avoid mutex locks, 
// but too long for atomic operations

#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

union Node
{
    std::atomic_flag access = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT; // one byte
    struct
    {
        uint32_t reserved : 8;
        uint32_t size : 23;
        uint32_t isnull : 1;
    } bits;
};

class SpinLock
{
public:
    inline SpinLock(std::atomic_flag &access, bool locked=true)
     : mAccess(access) { if(locked) lock(); }

    inline ~SpinLock() { unlock(); }

    inline void lock()
    { while (mAccess.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) {} }

    // each attempt will take about 10-30 clock cycles
    inline bool try_lock(unsigned int attempts=0)
    {
        while(mAccess.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
        {
            if (! attempts) return false;
            -- attempts;
        }

        return true;
    }

    inline void unlock()
    { mAccess.clear(std::memory_order_release); }

private:
    std::atomic_flag &mAccess;
};

int getSize(int i) { return (i * i); }

void aFn(int &i, Node &d)
{
    SpinLock lock(d.access, false);

    // ... some code...

    // manually locking/unlocking can be tighter
    lock.lock();
    if (!d.bits.isnull)
    {
        d.bits.size += getSize(i);
    }
    d.bits.isnull ^= true; // alternates
    lock.unlock();

    // ... some other code...
}

void aFn2(int &i, Node &d)
{
    // When you need to lock the entire function
    SpinLock lock(d.access);
    if (!d.bits.isnull)
    {
        d.bits.size += getSize(i);
    }
}   // returning will free up the lock as well

int main(void)
{
    Node f;
    f.bits.size = 0;
    f.bits.isnull = 0;

    std::thread *p[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++ i)
    {
        p[i] = new std::thread([&f] (int i) { aFn(i, f); }, i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        p[i]->join();
        delete p[i];
    }

    std::cout << "size: " << sizeof(f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count: " << f.bits.size << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to simply have a single `std::atomic<uint32_t>`, and members to get/set the bits? You'd still have to spin in edge cases, but it wouldn't require a size change for a lock.

Comment: Yes, you can use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752087/13797696) to manipulate the bits of atomic integral numbers by #defining the bits. As there isn't any atomic bitfield (mostly for programming convenience purpose), I suggested to burry a lock with a union and take care of the bitfield operations by locking, but the lock sacrifices 8 bits, not 1, and will be slower.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes, that would be *much* better than a hand-rolled naive spinlock which doesn't use `_mm_pause()` or check read-only for availability after a failure like `pthread_spinlock_t` would.  A `std::mutex` on good OSes like GNU/Linux is about this cheap in the low-contention case, too, but I seem to recall Windows is stuck with something worse until the next ABI change.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Anyway, a CAS retry loop around a bitfield update on a local temporary is similar to a spinlock in the un-contended case, but is lock-free so avoids the possibility of a thread going to sleep while holding the lock and blocking everything for up to 10 ms.

Comment: My example with a spinlock is meant to address the usual case when you want to manipulate bitfield variables that are more than 1 bits in size that spin-locking will most likely be more efficient, but you do not want to hand off the control back to system with a `std::mutex` (and you want to let the compiler generate the code for bitfield operations). If your code is tight enough, you can lock at the beginning of the function with `SpinLock lock(d.access)` in the example, and skip all manual locking and unlocking, and then returning the function will free the access.

Comment: If you're going to hand-roll anything with `std::atomic`, use `struct bits expected = shared.load();` / `do { auto desired = update(expected); } while(!shared.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired) );`  That's at least as efficient as a spinlock, unless the bitfield manipulation on a local temporary is so expensive that retrying it hurts.  It has the major advantage of being lock-free, impossible to sleep at a moment that blocks other threads.

Comment: Mostly I think it's a very bad idea to suggest a hand-rolled spinlock without at least mentioning the two major things that production-quality spinlocks do: x86 `_mm_pause()` in the retry loop, and checking read-only before trying another atomic RMW. ([Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246263)).  And mentioning the possible major downsides like sleeping for a timeslice (maybe 10 ms) with the lock held if there are more threads than cores.

Comment: I agree any kind of locking will be slower. I added an atomic exchange example to my response for simpler tasks for the given data structure. It can quickly add a lot of additional programming time for bitfields. Depending on the complexity of task, one may still have to use a spin lock...

Comment: @kisa: Why would it add a lot of time? There's only <33 operators in C++, which can be built into a single class, and from then on it's free.

Comment: @kisa: like so: https://ideone.com/ZDMuTp

Comment: @MooingDuck right, I see your use case and agree it is possible to manipulate data fields atomically with some software support, but I would not want to use such semi-hardware supported atomic bitfields in order to synchronize multithreading. I suspect manipulating a collection of counters and flags stored in one aggregate type by retrying to read and write atomically over and over with many threads will still hurt the performance. BTW, I did not think the `SpinLock` class I suggested above has inherent `_mm_pause()` operations while retrying, does it?

Comment: No, you have no `_mm_pause()`. But instead of retrying read-writes on the flags, your spilock retries read-writes on a lock. Once it gets the write, then it modifies the flags, then writes on the lock again. That hurts performance *more* than the atomic flags.

Comment: @MooingDuck There are no locks in my code, it’s using strictly `std::atomic_flag` type for quick synchronization needs. BTW, I suppose testing a null bit in a counter may be useful in some randomly and rarely accessed variables where zeroth element is indexed as well.

Comment: @kisa: You absolutely is a lock in your code. The `SpinLock` class *itself* is a busy-lock.

Comment: I wrote https://ideone.com/ptZ4rR to compare the performances but for some reason I can't coax https://quick-bench.com/ to run it. I keep getting `504 Gateway Time-out`

Comment: I suspect we can improve our versions by putting `std::this_thread::yield();` in the locking loops.

Comment: @MooingDuck I should give you a complete example for benchmarking purposes, but we are at the middle of a project with an urgent deadline, and I need to think of a good use case for everything discussed here. I will respond in a week.